# Having trouble creating a parameter to generate a random name

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am very new to programing and I am having a difficult time understanding  how to create this parameter.  These are the parameters I think I figured out the second two but I don't understand how I should write the first one.

Guidelines are:

> - Complete the statement that creates the Candy object c.
> - First parameter - Use r to generate a random integer up to numNames (was used as a string to set the array size). Use this value as an index into the candyNames array, thus giving you a random candy name.
> - Second parameter - Use r again, this time to generate a random floating point number.
> - Third parameter - Use r again, this time to generate a random integer that is less than 4. However, you must add 1 to it to insure that it is always greater than 0.

```
     Candy c = new Candy( r.nextInt() ,r.nextFloat()  , r.nextInt(4) +1 );
```

Comment: Should the last one be less than 4 *after* the addition of 1, or before?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

You have an array of names, and want to select a random name from it.

To access an specific position in the array, you use
`candyNames[1]"`

You can switch that 1 to a random Integer:

`Candy c = new Candy( candyNames[r.nextInt(numNames)],r.nextFloat(), r.nextInt(3) +1 );`

Answer (score 1):

> First parameter - Use r to generate a random integer up to
>   numNames(was used as a string to set the array size). Use this value
>   as an index into the candyNames array, thus giving you a random candy
>   name.

```
candyNames(r.nextInt(numNames))
```

> Second parameter - Use r again, this time to generate a random
>   floating point number.

```
r.nextFloat()
```

> Third parameter - Use r again, this time to generate a random integer
>   that is less than 4. However, you must add 1 to it to insure that it
>   is always greater than 0.

```
r.nextInt(3) + 1
```

All together:

```
Candy c = new Candy(candyNames[r.nextInt(numNames)], r.nextFloat(), r.nextInt(3) + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Candy c = new Candy(candyNames[r.nextInt(numNames)], r.nextFloat(), r.nextInt(3) + 1);
```

Note, that the last Parameter needs to be r.nextInt(3) because the result has to be **less** than 4. Your code gives values from 1 to 4 inclusive.